# What are the performance characteristics of caret or $ in a MySQL REGEXP?

Tags: mysql, sql

> Query the list of CITY names from STATION which have vowels (i.e., a,
> e, i, o, and u) as both their first and last characters. Your result
> cannot contain duplicates.

Solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE 
    CITY REGEXP '^[aeiou]' AND
    CITY REGEXP '[aeiou]$'
```

Why was this solution downvoted a lot in [a forum](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-8/forum)? Is there any performance issue with a query like that, or is it bad practice somehow?

Comment: There are two conditions when only one is needed (see the regexes which combine both parts).

Comment: `/^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$/`

Comment: @steffen would '^[aeiou].+[aeiou]$' work better? * being "zero or more instance preceding it", wouldn't that match the case where we just have a vowel at the end of the string with no vowel at the start? (which is not what we want here, since we need both first and last character as vowel)

Comment: @graygoo `.*` = any character, zero or more times; the wildcard is for the dot only. So that regex would match `a`, `aba`, but not `ba`. It's not clear to me whether a city like `a` should match having the same character for first and last char (well I'd expect it to be included in the results), but I guess there aren't any one-character-cities anyway.

Comment: Sounds like homework?

Comment: @steffen - That misses the city in Norway called Å.

Comment: `^` requires less effort in a regexp.  However, as Bittu says, fetching the rows is the expensive part of the task.

Comment: @Rick James Nope, I'm just learning python for personal projects, and am doing challenges from the hackerrank website.

Comment: Personal projects are a good way to learn.  Keep the questions coming.  "Bad practice" smacks of "opinion", hence closing the Question.  "Performance" questions are less likely to be closed.  (I edited the Title; maybe it will stay open this time.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no performance issue with using these. They are instead faster way of searching strings in comparison to nested queries. On HackerRank forum, I have seen many other course comments also where answers were right but people were just downvoting. Though the two lines in 'where city REGEXP' part can be combined and written in one line, the time complexity for both will be same. If you want to know more about Regex in MySQL, you can follow this post :-

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-regular-expressions-regexp/